# cant load json data from action in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, action

im trying to load some json data in my simple web app. i'm gonna show you the steps. First my action is:

```
const jsonData =
  [
    {
      "id": "00260001010000000001",
      "accountNumber": "0026.0001.01.0000000001",
      "description": "My account #1",
      "balance": 42.0,
      "balanceAvailable": 42.0,
      "currency": "EUR"
    },
    {
      "id": "00260001010000000002",
      "accountNumber": "0026.0001.01.0000000002",
      "description": "My account #2",
      "balance": 43.0,
      "balanceAvailable": 43.0,
      "currency": "EUR"
    }
  ];

export function inAccountList(jsonData) {
  return {
    type: 'ACCOUNT_LIST',
    payload: jsonData
  };
}
```

Then, i create my reducer account-list-reducer like this:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';

function mergeState(state, newState) {
  return state.merge(newState);
}

    export default function (state = Map(), action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'ACCOUNT_LIST':
          return mergeState(state, action.payload);
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

and

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import AccountListReducer from './account_list_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  accounts: AccountListReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Then, i create my accountListContainer like this:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import AccountList from '../../components/AccountList';


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  // FIXME account number and available balance mapping.
  return { accounts: state.get('accounts').map(account => account.toJS()) };
}

const AccountListContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(AccountList);

export default AccountListContainer;
```

and my AccountList view is:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';
import AccountEntry from '../AccountEntry';

const AccountList = ({ accounts }) => (
  <div className="account-list">
    <h4 className="table-header">Accounts</h4>
    <Table hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Account Number</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Balance</th>
          <th>Available Balance</th>
          <th>Currency</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {accounts.map((account, i) =>
          <AccountEntry
            key={account.id} idx={i + 1}
            {...account}
          />
      )}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  </div>
);


export default AccountList;
```

But it's not working. it doesn't show the dummy data in that were written in the jsonData. Do you have any idea what;s going on?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Your store's state is not an ImmutableJS object, rather your reducers are ImmutableJS objects inside it. Try state.accounts.toJS() in your mapStateToProps function

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Mr Mitchell but this doesn work. it shows me an error caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJS' of undefined

Comment: Try sticking some break points in mapStateToProps and see what is in your store. You should have an empty map on inital state and then some sort of Immutable object once ACCOUNT_LIST has been dispatched. The error you're getting suggests that state.accounts doesn't exist when it's being invoked

Comment: Thanks again for your rapid response....but why state.accounts doesnt exists? do you see an error in my code?

Comment: Have you wrapped your app with the store using <Provider store={store}> ?

Comment: const store = createStore(reducers);  ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));

Answer (score 0):

I think the call to action creator `inAccountList` is absent

1. pass the action creator `inAccountList` in `mapDispatchToProps`
2. call the action in componentDidMount of `AccountList` component